# How can I locate a stolen MacBook that didn't have Find My Mac turned on?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, security

My MacBook was stolen. Unfortunately, I didn't have Find My Mac turned on. Is there any way to track it's whereabouts so I can recover it?

Comment: Any chance you had Backblaze on there? Also, if you have login credentials on your computer and they were to login to your Gmail account, you likely will be able to see the location of their activity. Of course, the possibility of you being successful tracking them via Gmail likely is offset by the possibility of them using your account for nefarious activity and going so far as to reset your password. It is an option, though.

Comment: I have seen "thieves" that took pictures with the webcam which where saved to the camera roll and synced to iCloud. Long read, but nice http://www.buzzfeed.com/mjs538/i-followed-my-stolen-iphone-across-the-world-became-a-celebr#.jflMNxr3V

Answer (score 2):

Without Find My Mac turned on via your iCloud account, you are going to have to rely on the kindness of strangers or local law enforcement to get it back.

**Edit:**

And my experience with a stolen computer was that even having Find My Mac enabled didn't help me get the computer back. The police would not use the location information to recover the computer. It is mostly for finding a lost computer or deleting your data so the thieves cannot gain access to your data.